# TexShop entry in "open with" on Mac OS X

Tags: mactex, editors, texshop, mac

I'm aware this is a question concerning Mac OS X and TeX, but I guess people here already had similar issues.

MacTeX comes with TexShop. However, if I right klick a `.tex`-file, this editor doesn't show up in the "Open with" dialog. Do I really have to manually edit the `.plist` or something to get them associated under Mac? Every other editor works (eg. TeXmaker..).

Comment: rightclick -> goto `Open With` -> `Other` -> look for `TeXshop` in `Applications`-Folder -> check `Set as default`-box. You're done.

Comment: This sets the default for exactly this one file. I do not want that, neither do I want to set the default for all files of this type, which is on Cmd+I open with. Rather, I want TexShop to appear directly in the entries proposed after right click - "open with".

Comment: In wich form woul I add something there? The folder is empty for me, so I have no idea how the entries should look like..

Comment: I revoked my last comment as it actually involves a little coding. so here's a possible solution to your problem utilizing Automator: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2351508?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: This question is probably better suited for https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

1. Open a finder window
2. Right click on a `.tex` file and choose `Get Info`
3. Select in `open with` the application you want to use to open `.tex` files
4. Afterwards click `change all` to use this setting not only for this file but for all `.tex` files